# What can I do to speed up IntelliJ IDEA when handling akka-http routes?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, akka-http

Update of syntax highlighting is incredibly slow, when editing even a simple route definition. Updates take seconds, which really breaks the edit/will-this-compile flow.

I didn't have this before. Maybe something's changed. Are others experiencing it?

---

IntelliJ IDEA 2017.1.4
Build #IC-171.4694.23, built on June 6, 2017
JRE: 1.8.0_112-release-736-b21 x86_64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Mac OS X 10.12.5

Scala 2.12.2
akka-http 10.0.7

Comment: This got cured when I reorganized the code. It was inheriting from a trait that used same name (I don't remember which one) that also existed in akka-http. Import aliases made it to compile, but likely IDE was confused.

Answer (score 0):

This is a big nuisance for me too.  You can disable type-aware highlighting which may help.  Click the [T] icon in the lower-right corner.